# why this sql with "LEFT JOIN" can improve a lot?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

[image]

sql like this,it only need 0.33s,
but when i change "LEFT JOIN" to "JOIN",like this
[image]

it need 10s more,is anyone can explain why?
I have index on im_callback_msg_body ,the column is "call_id"
the "EXPAIN" command show execute plan like that
"LEFT JOIN" [image]
"JOIN" [image]

Comment: possible duplicate - [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: I know the differentce between "JOIN" and "left JOIN",what I don't konw is when i use "join",it get 1596 record cost 10.7s, when use "left join",it get 3681 record only cost 0.33s

Answer (score 0):

Change `SELECT 1` to `SELECT COUNT(*)` and you might discover a useful clue.

Both will speed up with:

`up` needs `INDEX(mobile)`
`e` needs `INDEX(msg_from)`

Then we can discuss performance.

What other info does it say in the Extra column?